# Bootable Kubuntu USB not recognized

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, kubuntu

I have downloaded Kubuntu 20.04.2 and flashed it onto a USB stick (the same one that I used to get a bootable version of ubuntu 20.04 working on this laptop), but when I try to boot it from a Toshiba that has Windows 7 I get the following error: `isolinux.bin missing or corrupt`. The laptop is from around 2011 I think.

In addition to selecting the USB from BIOS, I have tried changing the priority order of what boots first so that the USB stick gets priority. I have also tried switching USB ports to see if that might help.

I plan on reflashing the USB stick and potentially even trying to create a bootable DVD. However, I was wondering if this issue goes beyond that? I am not really sure what to do here (especially if both reflashing and the DVD does not work). Is it possible I need to reformat the USB to fat or something else?

Happy to list more information if needed.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks in advance.